# Безопасность ключа

Tags: безопасность

<pre>
Есть несколько клиент-сервером (для примера возьмем 5) - чат.
1 - администратор, но он знает только адрес 2 и 3-его пользователя.
2-5 - пользователи. Каждый из которых знает только 2 адреса других пользователей (например только соседей).
Теперь возьмем и запустим несколько чатов (со своими администраторами и такими самими характеристиками). Стоит указать то, что может случиться так, что несколько (или все) пользователи будут под контролем разных администраторов.
Для безопасности воспользуемся ключом авторизации (у каждого администратора свой)
Теперь представьте:
Администратор должен получить доступ к пользователю 4, но он не знает его адреса, а знает адрес только пользователя 2 и 3, а пользователь 2 знает адрес к 4-ому.
Пользователь 2 не хочет выдавать администратору адрес 4-ого пользователя. Следовательно трафик идет от администратора к 4-ому пользователю через 2-ого пользователя.
И ключ авторизации проходит через 4-ого пользователю.
4-ый пользователь узнал ключ и следовательно он может быть администратором.
Тоже самое может быть с любим пользователем (даже во время простой передачи сообщений к пользователю к пользователю, т.к ключ один)
<strong>Как можно избежать утечки ключа?</strong>
</pre>

Comment: Существуют схемы обмена ключами с использованием приватных/публичных ключей. Например, https защищен от  man-in-the-middle.

Answer (score 1):

Если передавать всю информацию через посредника, при условии что сам посредник активно мониторит трафик и готов к попытке перехвата ключа - никак. 
Почитай про так называемй способ "Человек посередине" вроде пишется так: man-in-middle.
Так что единственный вариант - уже знать некую информацию которую знает только 4 пользователь и тот кто к нему подключается. Если изначально создавать соединение через других - гарантировать безопасность невозможно. По крайне мере я про такое не знаю.